# Really, really, really strange login behavior

Tags: gnome, 16.04, login, lightdm

It's a bit hard to describe this problem, but I'll try my best.

---

- I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my family's Intel NUC, knowing that it was *probably* user friendly enough for them to use.
- However, a certain problem occurs at login time, I think only when there are other users logged in.

Today I opened the computer and found myself on another user's lock-screen.

The only way to get out of said screen was to go through all `tty` consoles, Until I found one that allowed me to switch accounts.

I put in my password, and then:

- The computer sort of froze
- The display shut off

Moving the mouse brought me to my own lock screen.

I entered my password again, and the screen went black. I switched `tty` consoles, which brought me back to the login screen. I switched again, at which point my account was finally usable.

**What is this?** It doesn't happen on my Lenovo Thinkpad, or on my other custom built desktop.

And all were installed using the same flash drive...